# Yii2 could not find pdo driver

Tags: php, web, yii2

When I work with DB with Yii2 Framework strange error occurs.

> Caused by: PDOException
>     could not find driver

*extension=pdo_mysql.so* in my *php.ini* is also uncommented. I'm using PHP 7.1. What's wrong?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: And did you restart your webserver?

Comment: @omerowitz I'm using Manjaro Linux, and yes, I've tried to restart my server.

Comment: Yii2 used MySQLi PDO driver. Try uncommenting extension=pdo_mysqi.so